# Angular hide parent div when no items in the child

Tags: angular

This is my html

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around flex-wrap">
    <div *ngFor="let f of files$ | async" class="card m-2 card-size">
    </div>
</div>
```

When there are no items in the `files$` observable, I see a small border of the parent. I have tried `border-0` etc but no effect. Is it possible to hide the parent div when the child div has no items?

Comment: use `*ngIf` to only render the parent div when `files$.length` is bigger than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution but you can try like this :

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="files$ | async as files">
  <ng-container *ngIf="files.length > 0">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around flex-wrap">
      <div *ngFor="let f of files" class="card m-2 card-size">
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks @PVermeer ! Effectively, you can place the second `*ngIf` into the container div.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="files$ | async as files">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around flex-wrap" *ngIf="files.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let f of files" class="card m-2 card-size">
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Why is this not the best solution?  Also the second `*ngIf` can be placed on the child div so there's no need for a second `<ng-container>`.

Comment: @PVermeer Not sure, I think it can be improved, that's it (: